# How do I pass data into a Modal using React/Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog

I have a table and when the user clicks on a row in the table I want to show the row data in a Modal diagram. The user will then be able to edit this data and then update it to a server.

I am using Next.js to build the website and I have tried many different React solutions but none of them seem to work. I am looking for a solid, easy solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a **reusable** modal component in this scenario, I do it something like this in my project.

This is going to be a completely reusable component, which is gonna wrap on to anything you pass in and convert that into a modal.

**React** is super powerful we just need to know how to use it !!

> Modal component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import classes from './Modal.css';
import Aux from '../../../hoc/Auxiliary/Auxiliary';
import Backdrop from '../Backdrop/Backdrop';

class Modal extends Component {

    shouldComponentUpdate ( nextProps, nextState ) {
        return nextProps.show !== this.props.show || nextProps.children !== this.props.children;
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Aux>
                <Backdrop show={this.props.show} clicked={this.props.modalClosed} />
                <div
                    className={classes.Modal}
                    style={{
                        transform: this.props.show ? 'translateY(0)' : 'translateY(-100vh)',
                        opacity: this.props.show ? '1' : '0'
                    }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </Aux>
        )
    }
}

export default Modal;
```

> Backdrop component

```
import React from 'react';

import classes from './Backdrop.css';

const backdrop = (props) => (
    props.show ? <div className={classes.Backdrop} onClick={props.clicked}></div> : null
);

export default backdrop;
```

Well don't get confused about Auxiliary, it's just a **HOC** which avoid adding an extra wrapper div

> Auxiliary HOC

```
const Aux = (props) => props.children;

export default Aux;
```